# VDI size error on Oracle VirtualBox 7

Tags: virtualbox, vdi

I copied a large 100Gb file into **VDI** successfully using the shared folder option on Linux guest OS. But the VDI size on Windows host OS doesn't enlarge as expected.

It remains at 2048kb the size it was created. How do I fix this? I'm using Oracle **VirtualBox7** with guest additions installed.

Comment: Can you try this again with a Guest Size of (say) 125GB?

Comment: Please describe in detail how you've set this up and copied the file. Show us your config of shared folders, explain how you have mounted the shared folder in Linux and which programs or commands you have used to copy the file. Also where it was copied. Include output of `mount` command. Use the [Edit] button to add all this info.

Comment: (If the file is 2K in size, then either you're looking at the wrong VDI or there's no Linux installed on that drive, so you're probably booting off a live CD and copying files into RAM)